# Accordion not closing manually

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an accordion that does not close manually, and I can't figure it out why.

I added the option that the first tab to be open as default, and also, to close automatically when another is opened.

Can you help me?

```css
.so-tab {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.so-tab label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 25px 0 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.so-tab input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.so-tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .35s;
}
/* :checked */
.so-tab input:checked ~ .so-tab-content {
  max-height: none;
}
/* Icon */
.so-tab label::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}
.so-tab input[type=radio] + label::after {
  content: "+";
}
.so-tab input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
  content: "\25BC";
}
.so-tab input[type=radio]:checked + label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}
.so-tab input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="so-accordion-wrapper">
  <div class="so-tab">
    <input id="so-tab-1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked="checked">
    <label for="so-tab-1">Details</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="so-tab">
    <input id="so-tab-2" type="radio" name="tabs">
    <label for="so-tab-2">Fabric / Care</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="so-tab">
    <input id="so-tab-3" type="radio" name="tabs">
    <label for="so-tab-3">Delivery</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="so-tab">
    <input id="so-tab-4" type="radio" name="tabs">
    <label for="so-tab-4">Return</label>
    <div class="so-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see it in action [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GRZ0F0MH29XV), don't forget to hit "RUN" to run the code.

Thank you for your time

Comment: It looks good in your example. What do you mean cannot close manually?

Comment: @ikhvjs If I try to close one, It doesn't work

Comment: Because it's a `radio-button`. And you can't deselect a radio-button. Only select another one. That's why it switches from one to another, but doesn't close when you click on the selected

Comment: Look this example - https://www.massimodutti.com/gb/men/get-your-cart-ready/polos/100%25-cotton-short-sleeve-polo-shirt-c1736993p9152501.html?colorId=420 @Michel

Comment: And then where? If you mean the Details / Fabric / Delivery section, thats a `<ul><li>` list with javascript, not radio buttons

Comment: @Michel , ah ok I´m noob sorry, so it's impossible to do in the way I did? :s

Comment: No, because as I said, you can't deselect a radio-button.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Michel ! I will now look for some simple javascript accordions then.

Comment: Found [an example](https://codepen.io/raubaca/pen/PZzpVe) using a checkbox that autocloses, but it doesn't work very smooth

Comment: @Michel You're the man! That's a start, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this](https://codepen.io/villa7/pen/grPddp) HTML/CSS accordion that closes tabs automatically when another is open and also let closes manually :) No js needed

```
<body>
<nav class="accordion arrows">
    <header class="box">
        <label for="acc-close" class="box-title">Accordion menu</label>
    </header>
    <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="cb1" />
    <section class="box">
        <label class="box-title" for="cb1">Readme</label>
        <label class="box-close" for="acc-close"></label>
        <div class="box-content">Click on an item to open. Click on its header or the list header to close.</div>
    </section>
    <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="cb2" />
    <section class="box">
        <label class="box-title" for="cb2">Read me too</label>
        <label class="box-close" for="acc-close"></label>
        <div class="box-content">Add the class 'arrows' to nav.accordion to add dropdown arrows.</div>
    </section>
    <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="cb3" />
    <section class="box">
        <label class="box-title" for="cb3">Item 3</label>
        <label class="box-close" for="acc-close"></label>
        <div class="box-content">Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque finibus tristique nisi, maximus ullamcorper ante finibus eget.</div>
    </section>

    <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="acc-close" />
</nav>
```